# Unknown value appearing for session level custom dimension created in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have created a session level custom dimension called signedIn in Google Analytics which im setting to the value 'true' for logged in website users. I can see the data for the same in Google Analytics but in addition to the stats for the value 'true', i also see some extra values for the signedIn custom dimension in the custom report i created as can be seen from the below screenshot.

[image]

What is the meaning of 'CampId:8, VarName: Control' and 'CampId:8, VarName: Partner-Content' and why does it show up as values for the session level custom dimension, signedIn, that i have created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CampId` and `VarName` are variables introduced by VWO for A/B and multivariate experiments executed on your site [[reference]](https://vwo.com/knowledge/how-to-integrate-with-google-universal-analytics/).

It is very likely that the custom dimension configured for your VWO/GA integration is the same as the one you are using to measure the state of your logged in users.

The workarounds here are to either:

- Change the custom dimension index used for tracking the state of your logged in users; or
- Log in to VWO and change the custom dimension index used to track experiments